# fetch clipboard text and remove hyphens

Tags: clipboard, trim

I'm running Mac OS 10.9 and I use the `Text to Speech` feature which allows you to use a hotkey that reads selected text in any application. I use this feature for reading out-loud PDF documents in Preview (Apple's PDF viewer).

The problem is that the selected text usually has word-break hyphens. The result is the `Text to Speech` feature doesn't read out the text properly.

Example:

[image]

Question:

Can you write me a short bash shell script that removes hyphens from the text in the clipboard? I will use automator too, so I can assign a hotkey, and to send the script's output to the Speak Text feature.

**Edit:** (in reply to  goldilocks's comment) Automator allows me to copy selected text to the clipboard followed by a shell script followed by the Speak Text feature. See image below.

[image]

**2nd Edit:** in fact there might be a more concise way of accomplishing this:

[image]

under the 'Pass input' option there is a 'as argument' option. I'm not sure whether this means I can skip the 'copy to clipboard' action in the first image, but I thought I'd mention it just in case.

Comment: "Selected text" is not the same as text in the clipboard.  If the application reads *selected text*, you may be out of luck unless OSX provides a means of working on that buffer.

Comment: @goldilocks Please see my most recent edit. OS X does provide the means via automator. All i need the shell script to do is fetch the data in the clipboard, remove the hyphens, and print it out. The simple `echo` command I used (in the photo above) successfully spoke the text, "clipboard text here"

Comment: I see you removed your comment on my answer. If for whatever reason the newlines have been stripped and replaced with spaces your `sed 's/- //'` would work, otherwise you need the longer one to deal with them.

Comment: It seems the script works now, but not in all instances. Based on my tests, it seems the `Speak Text` feature doesn't like formatted text. Is there code I can add so that the text piped to `Speak Now` isn't formatted? BTW, I genuinely appreciate the help.

Comment: Probably, you would need to post an example of the raw text stream. I can have a look tomorrow. Btw, if you use `@Graeme` in your comment, I will get a notification for it.

Comment: Did it work with be formatted text after all then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Linux the following would work:

```
xsel | sed ':rep /-$/ {N; s/-\n//; b rep}' | xsel -i
```

On OSX I am largely guessing (although the `sed` script should work ok). `pbcopy` seems to the the command to use. Assuming there is a selection buffer on OSX and `pbcopy` works from it by default, this might work:

```
pbpaste | sed ':rep /-$/ {N; s/-\n//; b rep}' | pbcopy
```

Looking at the [online man page](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/pbcopy.1.html), it seems there are a number of 'pasteboards' that it can work with:

```
-pboard {general | ruler | find | font}
       specifies which pasteboard to copy to or paste from.  If no pasteboard is
       given,  the  general pasteboard will be used by default.
```

I have no idea which one (if any) is the one you want and I can't see any further documentation (although I haven't looked too deep). You could experiment with `pbpaste -pboard xxx` and see what comes out. There is a good chance one is for highlighted text while the other is for text copied with Cmd-C. Given a working option, you would just add it to both `pbpaste` and `pbcopy`.

The other thing that may go wrong is that `pbcopy` has issues reading and writing to the same pasteboard in at the same time. The simplest solution would be to use a non standard Unix utility called `sponge`. It is part of [moreutils](https://joeyh.name/code/moreutils/).  Again Linux-centrically:

```
pbpaste | sed ':rep /-$/ {N; s/-\n//; b rep}' | sponge | pbcopy
```

Otherwise use a variable:

```
selection=$(pbpaste | sed ':rep /-$/ {N; s/-\n//; b rep}')
echo "$selection" | pbcopy
```

#### Update

Assuming Automator uses the `stdout` of the shell script, you would just select the `to stdin` option (this is where the data arrives if it is piped to the script). The the shell script would simply be:

```
#!/bin/sh
sed ':rep /-$/ {N; s/-\n//; b rep}'
```